# Correct syntax for using special function call in call

Tags: r, function, syntax, nse

I'm interested in making use of a [**special call**](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#special-calls) within `call`/`eval` as in the code:

```
eval(call("mean", c(2,3)))
```

which will correctly produce result **2.5.** Now, I would like to use the same syntax with a [**special call**](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#special-calls).

### Example: `+`

1. Call:

   ```
   eval(call("`+`", c(2,3)))
   ```

   produces error:

   > Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "`+`"
2. Similarly with the call,

   ```
   eval(call("+", c(2,3)))
   ```

   does not produce desired results:

   ```
   [1] 2 3
   ```

---

Desired result should simply return vector of length 1 with single value **5** as obtained via `2 + 3` call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`eval(call("+", c(2,3)))` is working perfectly fine. You are calling unary plus with a vector, which returns the identical vector.

If you want to use binary plus, you need to supply two arguments:

```
eval(call("+", 2, 3))
#[1] 5
```

But `do.call` should be preferable in production code:

```
do.call("+", list(2, 3))
#[1] 5
```